# Different way to implement this trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger

I am new in APEX, so I was wondering if there is  a simpler way to write this trigger or this is the only approach?
Thank you in advance!

```
trigger RemovalCountsONProducts on NRProducts__c (before update){

    AggregateResult[] results =
    [SELECT NRProducts__c p, SUM(Qty_Received__c) q, SUM(Qty_Open__c) s
    FROM Removal_Detail__c
    WHERE NRProducts__c IN :Trigger.new
    GROUP BY NRProducts__c];

    //create  maps 

    // Qty_Received__c
    Map<Id, Decimal> totalsByParentId = new Map<Id, Decimal>();
    for(AggregateResult r : results){
        totalsByParentId.put((Id)r.get('p'), (Decimal)r.get('q'));
    }

    // Qty_Open__c
    Map<Id, Decimal> totalsByParentId2 = new Map<Id, Decimal>();
    for(AggregateResult r : results){
        totalsByParentId2.put((Id)r.get('p'), (Decimal)r.get('s'));
    }

    //We loop over the full list of parents being modified 

    for(NRProducts__c p : Trigger.new){
         //Set the summary field to either 0 or the total, depending on if the map contains the parent id
        p.Removal_Units_Received__c = totalsByParentId.containsKey(p.Id) ? totalsByParentId.get(p.Id) : 0;        
        p.Removal_Units_Open__c = totalsByParentId2.containsKey(p.Id) ? totalsByParentId2.get(p.Id) : 0;                    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger runs when NRProducts__c is updated. So when Removal_Detail__c objects are inserted, updated or deleted the sums on NRProducts__c will not change which is probably not what you want.

If you have to use triggers, I would expect instead for the trigger to be on insert, update or delete of Removal_Detail__c and to do an explicit update on NRProducts__c.

If you can use [rollup summary fields](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_defining_summary_fields.htm&language=en_US) on NRProducts__c instead (i.e. its a master-detail relationship and the 10 available rollups haven't been used) the trigger can be avoided altogether.

**PS**

If writing a trigger to update the parent NRProducts__c, you can do the update without querying NRProducts__c by setting the Id (obtained from the Removal_Detail__c.NRProducts__c field in the aggregate query) in the object constructor along with the fields you want to update like this:

```
NRProducts__c[] products = new NRProducts__c[] {};
...
    products.add(new NRProducts__c(
            Id = productId,
            Removal_Units_Received__c = r, 
            Removal_Units_Open__c = o
            ));
...
update products;
```

Comment: Keith, we already used the 10 rollups.

Comment: So how can I update these fields  when Removal_detail__c object is updated? if i am not able to use rollups

Comment: @carlos You can do a normal SOQL update of NRProducts__c from within the Removal_Detail__c trigger. Normally best to use a trigger that is "after insert, after update, before delete" and it takes a bit of care to get right so its worth Googling for examples.